# How to disable public access for app configuration in terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-app-configuration

I can create `azurerm_app_configuration` app configuaration for Azure app configuration.
And can create `azurerm_private_endpoint` using terraform.

But I didnot find out which terraform function can be used to disable public access, as image below.

[image]

Does anyone can help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just by creating the private endpoint, the **public access will be denied**. From [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/concept-private-endpoint):

> By default, when a private endpoint is added to your App Configuration store, all requests for your App Configuration data over the public network are denied. You can enable public network access by using the following Azure CLI command.

However, if you want to control this explicitly, then such a control is **not supported in TF**. There is github issue about that already:

- [Support for azurerm_app_configuration public_network_access_enabled](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/12876)

Comment: perhaps, you correct, I have to use command line in terraform to set public access on app configuration.